# SharePoint 2010 shade background using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I've got a question. I use SharePoint 2010 and I try to shade specific elements in a list. But these changes should only be applied on columns. So I have to search this column and then it should use the css styles with JavaScript. I don't want to use the SharePoint Designer.
Here is my JavaScript...where is the error?Until now it won't work.
I hope you can help me!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#diidSortCR_x0020_Status").val() == "CR Status") {

      $("td").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == 'Evaluated';
      }).css("background-color", "FF0000");

      $("td.ms-vb2").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == 'Approved';
      }).css("background-color", "00FF00");

      $("td").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == 'Ready to test';
      }).css("background-color", "D4D4D4");
});
```

Comment: `$("#diidSortCR_x0020_Status").val() == "CR Status") {` what's that? Indent your code properly and you should find these kind of errors easily.

Comment: it should compare the column with the value "CR Status", but how can I find after that the certain rules!

Comment: Nope. This is all wrong. Should it be in a `if` statement? You are closing a `)` which you didn't open and you open a `{` which you never close. Please check your code against simple syntax errors. And possibly use your javascript console.

Comment: Yeah OkI will check it, but I like to know how I can compare the headlines of a sharepoint list against one value. "CR Status" and then execute the other functions.